# How to send big sized syslog message to remote server in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, logging

I am developing one script which will GET logs from one application save in one file and PUSH to one syslog remote server. I can send log message which is small but my syslog message which is big, Due to this its getting break. Please help me with this.

I am using logger and NC to send syslog.

Using Logger

```
cat log.txt | logger -n 10.10.10.10
```

Using NC

```
value=`cat log.txt`

echo "$value"

echo -n "$value" | nc -4u -w1 10.10.10.10 514
```

File SIZE

```
root@prabhu:/home/teja/MalopInfo# ls -l --block-size=M log.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1M Jun  6 20:09 hello.txt
```

Help me with this.

Comment: You never asked a direct question. What is the issue?

Comment: So where does the problem arise, are you getting an error message?  Perhaps update your post including your script.  Also, is configuring your syslog such that it logs directly to a remote server an option?  Or did you only want the logs to be pushed to the remote server manually (when you run your script)?